# Proving that the map $f(x)=x^k$ is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and let $k$ be an integer relatively prime to the order of the group. Show that every element of g can be expressed as $x^k$ for some $x$ in $G$.

So this is equivalent to showing the map $f(x)=x^k$ is surjective. I don't know how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $f(x)=x^k$ is injective: 
If $f(x)=e$ then $x^k=e$ hence order of $x$ divide $k$ and $n$ , i.e the order of $x$ divide $\mathrm{gcd}(k,n)=1$, so $x=e$.

$f$ is injective and $G$ finite it is a bijection .

Answer (score 5):

Let $n$ the order of $G$ and since $k$ and $n$ are relatively prime the by the Bézout's theorem there's $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb Z$ such that
$$\alpha k+\beta n=1$$
so we get

$$g=g^{\alpha k+\beta n}=\left(g^\alpha\right)^k=x^k$$

Comment: +1 for this shows that the assumption about $G$ being abelian (implying that $f$ is a homomorphism) was not necessary.